# Docker doesn't get the environment variables and fails to start [Windows]

Tags: node.js, windows, docker, npm

I have 2 apps on the same container, both getting the env variables from the docker-compose.yml, one works, the other doesn´t. I have no issues starting it in Linux, but when using Windows, somehow it fails to send the env variables. Here is the error I'm getting:

```
internal/url.js:243
  throw error;
  ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL: nats://undefined:undefined@undefined:undefined
    at onParseError (internal/url.js:241:17)
    at new URL (internal/url.js:319:5)
    at Client.parseOptions (/opt/node_app/node_modules/nats/lib/nats.js:428:34)
    at new Client (/opt/node_app/node_modules/nats/lib/nats.js:221:8)
    at Object.exports.connect (/opt/node_app/node_modules/nats/lib/nats.js:250:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/node_app/lib/nats.js:6:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ms_template@1.0.0 start: `cross-env node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ms_template@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I also checked the Docker Desktop Inspect window and aparently the env variables are there, but it somehow fails to "load" them. The format I'm using is the followingÑ

```
 environment:
      server_user: "user"
      server_pass: "pass"
      server_port: 1234
      server_ip: nats
      node_env: production
      api_host: http://localhost:1234/api
      node_tls_reject_unauthorized: 0
```

Tried changing the "" for '' and nothing. Im sure it has something to do with the format change between Linux and Windows, the paths or other things around this.

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the env variables had to be in capital case

```
environment:
      SERVER_USER: "user"
      SERVER_PASS: "pass"
      SERVER_PORT: 1234
      SERVER_IP: nats
      node_env: production
      api_host: http://localhost:1234/api
      node_tls_reject_unauthorized: 0
```